# Structural type in method type parameterization in Scala?

Tags: scala

Consider the following Scala code (e.g., in REPL)

```
object A{def foo:Unit = {}}
object B{def foo:Unit = {}}

def bar[T <: Any {def foo: Unit}](param: T*):Unit = param.foreach(x => x.foo)

bar(A, A)  // works fine
bar(B, B)  // works fine
bar(A, B)  // gives error
```

The first two work fine. The third ones gives an error:

`error: inferred type arguments [ScalaObject] do not conform to method bar's type parameter bounds [T <: Any{def foo: Unit}]`

Are there any ways to do what I want?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is usually called structural typing, not duck typing. I edited your title. :)

I think that your problem is caused by defining the type parameter `T` and then using it in an invariant way. `T` can only refer to one concrete type, but you have parameters of different types `A` and `B`.

This works:

```
 def bar(param: {def foo: Unit}*) = param.foreach(x => x.foo)
```

Edit: Using a type *alias* also works:

```
 type T = {def foo: Unit}
 def bar(param: T*) = param.foreach(x => x.foo)
```

This works because the compiler will simply substitute the structural type in place of its alias, `T`. After the substitution, this example is exactly the same as the one above.

Comment: This is another one of those features that makes Scala so awesome.

Comment: Does it use reflection at runtime? I thought it should not use reflection because the error in my code occurs during compile.

Comment: It does use reflection at runtime. See Randall Schulz's explanation in this thread: http://www.scala-lang.org/node/6834

Comment: I believe that if the information is available at compile time, it should be possible to insert this information for use at runtime (unless I am missing something). Is there an example that can be exhibited to show that reflection is the only way to do it.