# Supply Structural type in method type parameterization at runtime?

Tags: scala, reflection, structural-typing

Follow-up to [this SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7602804/structural-type-in-method-type-parameterization-in-scala)

Suppose I have the code

```
def bar(param: {def foo: Unit}*) = param.foreach(x => x.foo)
```

This function causes object `param` to invoke a method named `foo`

[EDIT]

I was wondering if the following is possible (with or without reflection)

- `param` is fixed at compile time, the name of the function (in this case `foo`) is supplied at runtime
- both `param` and the name of the function `foo` are supplied at runtime
- `param` is fixed at compile time, the name of the function, the function parameters, values and return types are supplied at runtime.

I realize Structural typing already uses reflection. So my question is if Scala can take care of it or if I have explicitly use reflection in my code. I think the 3rd one requires reflection for which I can use the [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question:

1. At compile-time, the compiler checks that each `param` has indeed a method `foo` with the correct signature.
2. At runtime, reflection is used underneath to call the method `foo` of each `param`

So you don't need to use reflection yourself, but you should keep it mind that reflection will be used at runtime, and could potentially decrease performances.

Comment: The question is, if I didn't know the name of the function (in this case `foo`) to be called (e.g., ask the user to supply it).

Comment: Then you cannot rely on structural typing since, first step is at compile time (see answer). You should just use plain-old reflection.