# Would scala close the InputStream automatically?

Tags: scala, stream

I'm a newbie of scala and not familiar to the stream close mechanism. I wrote some code like this.

```
def loadResourceAsString(path: String) = {

  val is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(path)

  Source.fromInputStream(is).getLines().mkString("\n")

}
```

I found this in scala source code. The `Source` would return a BufferedSource which override close method to close the input stream.

```
def fromInputStream(is: InputStream)(implicit codec: Codec): BufferedSource =
  createBufferedSource(is, reset = () => fromInputStream(is)(codec), close = () => is.close())(codec)
```

If there was exception, would scala execute the close method by its own mechanism?

Or, should I close input stream in **finally** block explicitly just like java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short - no. 
`createBufferedSource` creates `BufferedSource` with given `close` function, but never calls neither for `reset` not for `close`

Comment: in this case how to close the inputstream in scala?

Answer (score 0):

May be this post will be helpful:
[Scala: “using” function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395984/scala-using-function).

It looks similar to C# using statement which I find very convenient.

Comment: Also look at [scala-arm](http://jsuereth.com/scala-arm/) if you need a consistent solution to resource management