# Iterator of InputStream: How to close the InputStreams?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, iterator

I have an Iterator[InputStream] which i map over to retrieve the individual results:

```
val streams: Iterator[InputStream[CustomType]] = retrieveStreams()
val results: Iterator[MyResultType] = streams flatMap (c => transformToResult(c))
```

This works as expected, meaning I can retrieve values of type MyResultType from the results iterator. The only problem I have is that the individual InputStreams are never being closed. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: See this answer: [Scala Input Stream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478455/would-scala-close-the-inputstream-automatically)

Comment: scalaz-stream solves this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no magic way to close it, or at least to guarantee that it will get closed. Thus you have to close each stream yourself. Take a look at the **Loan Pattern** which makes it less error prone: [Loaner Pattern in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762240/loan-pattern-in-scala).

In your case you don't have a single resource to release but rather a collection of resources, so adjust your custom loan pattern accordingly.

Since you are dealing with `Iterator` you might have unlimited supply of `InputStream`s, in that case your `transformToResult` function would have to close the stream or something else at the element level.

It could look something like this:

```
val streams: Iterator[InputStream[CustomType]] = retrieveStreams()
val results: Iterator[MyResultType] =
  streams flatMap (c => yourLoaner(c)(transformToResult))
```