# What's the right way to use scala.io.Source?

Tags: scala, scala-2.8

In many examples, it is described that you can use `scala.io.Source` to read a whole file like this:

```
val str = scala.io.Source.fromFile("test.txt").mkString()
```

But closing the underlying stream is not mentioned.

Why does Scala not provide a convenient way to do that such as with clause in Python? It looks useful but not difficult.

Is there any other better way to do that safely in Scala, I means to read a whole file?

Comment: Is it right to use Source this way not closing the underlying stream?

Comment: If you read the code of scala.io.Source, you will find that in fact it leaves the work of closing underlying stream to you. Amazing!

Comment: Consider instead using:
import java.nio.file.{Files, Path, Path}
val data = Files.readString(path)

Answer (score 47):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, the standard library provides a dedicated resource management utility: [`Using`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/util/Using$.html).

It can be used in this case with [`scala.io.Source`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/io/Source.html) as it extends [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) in order to read from a file and, no matter what, close the file resource afterwards:

```
import scala.util.Using
import scala.io.Source

Using(Source.fromFile("file.txt")) { source => source.mkString }
// scala.util.Try[String] = Success("hello\nworld\n")
```

Comment: Nice syntax, seems odd the language had to wait until so late to get this!

Answer (score 37):

For the sake of completeness

```
val testTxtSource = scala.io.Source.fromFile("test.txt")
val str = testTxtSource.mkString()
testTxtSource.close()
```

Should get things done.

Comment: Shouldn't this be in a `try` block and the `close()` in the `finally` block?

Comment: @robinst That would be a good thing and I agree with Daniel's answer (ie don't use scala.io.Source at all) However, it has come in useful at our Dojos where we do not write production code. Also, I would use an ARM library (rather than `try` `catch`) because `close()` could also throw an exception and I find it awkward to have a `try` `catch` `finally` within a `finally`.

Comment: This approach may cause a resource leak

Answer (score 30):

Scala's `io` library was just hack done to provide support for limited needs. There was an effort to provide a well-thought io library to Scala, which is currently hosted at [assembla](https://scala-incubator.assembla.com/wiki/show/scala-incubator), with a [github](https://github.com/scala-incubator/scala-io) repository as well.

If you are going to use I/O for anything more than reading the occasional file on short-lived processes, you'd better either use Java libraries, or look at the I/O support presently available in the compiler (which will require scala-compiler.jar to be distributed with the app).

Automatic resource management is provided since Scala 2.13 in the standard library (`scala.util.Using`). For older Scala versions look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2207425/53013), or at [this library](https://github.com/jsuereth/scala-arm/wiki/) (which is featured in the accepted answer at that question).

So, on Scala 2.13 or newer, this works correctly:

```
import scala.util.Using
import scala.io.Source

val tryStr: Try[String] = Using(Source.fromFile("test.txt"))(_.mkString())
```

Comment: Would you still recommend not using scala.io as of 2016?

Comment: @knub I haven't look at Scala 2.12 to see if something was improved there, but, otherwise, yes, I stand by the same recommendation.

Comment: In 2019, I am still seeing that the Java NIO.2 package is significantly more sophisticated than the io.Source package, to the point that it warrants use a Java library over a pure Scala solution (as much as that pains me to say).

Comment: Would it be better to do something like 
Using(new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.FileReader(infile)) { in =>
  val data = in.lines().iterator().asScala
  // do stuff here ???
It takes quite a few transforms to get the file into a stream of lines and finally into a form that you can do standard Scala operations on. Is there a better way if you want to use modern 2.13 and Java 11+?

Comment: @MurrayToddWilliams There are more compact ways with recent Java, but that would be a different question. Scala 2.13 added resource management to the standard library (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55440868/53013), which makes a solution such as proposed by Valentin Tihomirov (https://stackoverflow.com/a/33972743/53013) a practical way of doing it in Scala.

Answer (score 13):

I recommend [using the using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395984), which makes your code neater and more reliable

```
using(Source.fromFile("test.txt")){ _.mkString()}
```

Scala 2.13 added `Using` to the library. So, with the proviso that `Using.apply` returns a `Try`, on Scala 2.13 it becomes:

```
import scala.util.Using
import scala.io.Source

Using(Source.fromFile("test.txt"))(_.mkString)
```

Comment: @OsskarWerrewka mkString has no side effects, so the parentheses should be omitted, i.e. `using(Source.fromFile("test.txt")){ _.mkString}`