# How to read a file line by line and close it afterwards in Scala?

Tags: scala, readfile, line-by-line

Normally, they will tell you to

```
import scala.io.Source
for(line <- Source.fromPath("myfile.txt").getLines())
  println(line)
```

which seems to leave the file open. What is a closeable counterpart?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can close the `Source` and this will close your file.

```
import scala.io.Source

val source = Source.fromFile("myfile.txt")
for (line <- source.getLines())
   println(line)
source.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4509988/4563974) distracted me. I keep wondering, why do you all guys use fromPath instead of fromFile? My compiler says that `fromPath is not a member of Source` and I must use fromFile instead.

Comment: You could also draw attention to the [using approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33972743/4563974)

Comment: "why do you all guys use fromPath instead of fromFile?" You are one of those guys. Tbh I just copied this from your question. Actually there is no such method. I fixed my answer to use `fromFile`.