# Custom 'using' control structure in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm learning scala and like the ability to come up with custom control structure, and as there's no `using` structure to close resources, I thought it'd be handy to write one. Then I found this snippet of code from the book, Beginning Scala, by David Pollak.

```
  using (Source.fromFile("file")) { source =>
    println(source.mkString)
  }

  def using[A <: { def close() }, B](closable: A)(body: A => B): B = 
  try 
    body(closable)
  finally 
    closable.close()
```

But I wonder whether would be possible to have something like:

```
  using (val source = Source.fromFile("file")) println(source.mkString)
```

Comment: Related: [No. 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395984/scala-using-function) and [No. 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207425/what-automatic-resource-management-alternatives-exists-for-scala
)

Comment: AFAIK no, because you are using "source: in the different scope, not the one you declared it)) But you can use for comprehensions to do this (monads), and CPS-like style that you posted above looks good enough to me.

Answer (score 2):

As [vitalli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1573825/vitalii) suggests, the short answer is no (sadly). Hopefully if I explain the method definition and invocation you found in Pollak's book then it will become clear why.

```
 def using[A <: { def close() }, B](closable: A)(body: A => B): B
```

This using method definition has two parameter lists (see [currying](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/135)). Both lists have one parameter. The first parameter is a closable object (type `A`). The second is a function that goes from `A` to `B`.

When you invoke the method with this line:

```
using (Source.fromFile("file")) { source => println(source.mkString) }
```

The first argument is the return value of `Source.fromFile("file")` which is a closable [`BufferedSource`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.io.BufferedSource). The second argument is an [anonymous function](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/133) that: takes one argument `source`, has one statement in its body `println(source.mkString)` and returns `Unit`.

The Scala compiler automatically detects the type of `source` from the method definition and the first argument you supplied (a [`BufferedSource`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.io.BufferedSource)). You could refactor out that anonymous function and declare the type explicitly if you wanted too:

```
using(Source.fromFile("file"))(eg)
def eg(source: BufferedSource): Unit = println(source.mkString)
```

But of course, the anonymous function is much more concise!